# Pagination - How to add code to first page only

Tags: category, pagination

Please could someone point me in the right direction of how to add code to only the first page of our paginated results (Magento categories)?

This is what I've tried so far:

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) || ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/') === '') {
    echo "test";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL parameter for pagination is `p` and you can access it anywhere via request object:

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('p')
```

If the parameter is not present, this returns null. So you can check if you are on the first page in one condition:

```
if (Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('p') <= 1)
```